How to set up a master button in tkinter that deselects all items in the dropdown checkbox list without deleting the list?
I am trying to create a button to deselect all the checkboxes in my two lists but I have not been successful
this is my code
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import openpyxl
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('2200x820')
MainFrame = tk.Frame(window, width=385, height=460, relief='raised', borderwidth=1)
ButtonFrame = tk.Frame(MainFrame, width=375, height=30, relief='raised', borderwidth=1)
LabelFrame = tk.Frame(MainFrame, width=375, height=1, relief='raised', background="yellow", borderwidth=0)
LabelFrame1 = tk.Frame(MainFrame, width=375, height=1, relief='raised', background="yellow", borderwidth=0.5)


some_button = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text='Enter data', command=window.destroy)




values1 = ["Shein", "Pretty Little Thing","Mangnopop","Ru21","forever21","blunotes","Streetwearsociety","Saints","Charllote Russe","Fashionnova","Capella",
          "lulus","Missguide"]    


values = ["Shein", "Pretty\n Little Thing","Mangnopop","Ru21","forever21","blunotes","Streetwearsociety","Saints","Charllote Russe","Fashionnova","Capella",
          "lulus","Missguide"]      

combobox = ttk.Combobox(ButtonFrame, width=30)
combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(ButtonFrame, width=30)

combobox.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10)
combobox1.grid(row=2,column=2)



checkbuttons_vars = [tk.BooleanVar() for value in values]
checkbuttons_vars1 = [tk.BooleanVar() for value in values1]

checkbuttons = []
checkbuttons1 = []


for index, value in enumerate(values):
   checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(LabelFrame,text=value, variable=checkbuttons_vars[index])
   checkbutton.config(background="yellow", fg="black", font=("Fira Code", 8), 
                   selectcolor="white", relief="flat", padx=1, pady=1)
   checkbutton.pack(side="left",anchor="w",fill="both")
   checkbuttons.append(checkbutton)
   

for index, value in enumerate(values1):
   checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(LabelFrame1,text=value,offvalue = 0, variable=checkbuttons_vars1[index])
   checkbutton.config(background="yellow", fg="black", font=("Fira Code", 8), 
                   selectcolor="white", relief="flat", padx=1, pady=1)
   checkbutton.pack(side="left",anchor="w",fill="both")
   checkbuttons1.append(checkbutton)



def update_combobox():
   selected_values = [value for value, var in zip(values, checkbuttons_vars,) if var.get()]
   selected_values1 = [value for value, var in zip(values1, checkbuttons_vars1,) if var.get()]
   combobox.configure(width=40, height=7)
   combobox.delete(0, tk.END)
   combobox.insert(0," , " .join(selected_values,))
   combobox.insert(0," , ")
   combobox.insert(0,"  , ".join(selected_values1))
   
      



def update_combobox1():
   selected_values = [value for value, var in zip(values, checkbuttons_vars) if var.get()]
   selected_values1 = [value for value, var in zip(values1, checkbuttons_vars1,) if var.get()]
   combobox1.configure(width=40, height=7)
   combobox1.delete(0, tk.END)
   combobox1.insert(0, ", ".join(selected_values))
   combobox1.insert(0," , ")
   combobox1.insert(0,"  ,  ".join(selected_values1))



def deselect():
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
     if isinstance(widget,tk.Checkbutton):
            widget.deselect()


deselect = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text="deselect all", anchor="nw",command=deselect())
deselect.grid(row=1,column=5)

update_button = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text="Update", anchor="nw",command=update_combobox)
update_button.grid(row=1,column=3)

update_button1 = tk.Button(ButtonFrame, text="Update", anchor="nw",command=update_combobox1)
update_button1.grid(row=2,column=3)


for frame in [MainFrame, LabelFrame, LabelFrame1, ButtonFrame,]:
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    frame.pack_propagate(0)

for widgetin [some_button]:
    widget.pack(expand=True, fill='x', anchor='s',ipady=10)

window.mainloop()

I am creating a computer based system that allows a user to choose a variety of items from the checkbox and update the items each in a separate combobox. I want the user to be able to deselect the items with one click using the deselect button.
Any idea will be much appreciated

Your code has many syntax errors, where it looks like you tried to interject comments with invalid syntax.

Please try to pare this down to a [mre], as it's likely much of this code is not pertinent to the issue at hand.

am still a beginner with python can you guide me the proper way to go about it

Typo error for widgetin [some_button]: should be for widget in [some_button]:

At least part of the problem is this block of code:
for widget in window.winfo_children():
    if isinstance(Widget,tk.Checkbutton):
        Widget.deselect()

You are iterating over a list of widgets using widget (lowercase "w") but then comparing Widget (uppercase "W") in the condition inside the loop. Widget will never be a checkbutton because it is a class imported from tkinter, not an actual widget.
If you had imported tkinter using the best practice of import tkinter as tk -- and only that method -- python would have warned you what Widget is undefined. However, since you also do from  tkinter import *, Widget gets imported.
Since you are saving the checkbuttons in lists, it seems to make more sense to iterate over checkbuttons and checkbuttons1 if your goal is to reset all of the checkbuttons.

Can you help illustrate how i can iterate over checkbuttons and checkbuttons1
